# Unable to SSH into switch: Key exchange or Algorithm Negotiation failed on hold

Tags: ssh, switch, d-link

Referred here by [Network Engineering Stack Exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56957/unable-to-ssh-into-switch-key-exchange-or-algorithm-negotiation-failed).

I am having a D-link 1510-28 switch to which I am trying to SSH into.

Upon trying the command:

```
srajan@srajan-Virtual-Machine:~$ ssh admin@10.82.64.5
Unable to negotiate with 10.82.64.5 port 22: no matching cipher found. Their offer: 3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,twofish-cbc,twofish256-cbc,twofish192-cbc,twofish128-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,arcfour,cast128-cbc
```

I also tried upgrading it to the latest firmware available, but to no avail.
After googling, I tried using this

```
srajan@srajan-Virtual-Machine:ssh -c aes256-cbc admin@10.82.64.5
Received disconnect from 10.82.64.5 port 22:3: Disconnected: Key exchange or Algorithm Negotiation failed
Disconnected from 10.82.64.5 port 22
```

As suggested on NE Stack Exchange comments, I also tried this but received the same error.

```
C:\Users\xyz>ssh -c aes256-cbc -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 admin@10.82.64.5
Received disconnect from 10.82.64.5 port 22:3: Disconnected: Key exchange or Algorithm Negotiation failed
Disconnected from 10.82.64.5 port 22
```

I have attached the full debug log here as this site considers it as spam.
[Full Debug log](https://pastebin.com/H9vwzu0Z)

**EDIT**: The second command verbose log can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/AtjuD5pU).

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by changing the RSA key length on the switch from 768 bit to 2048 bit Host key. The error stopped showing up after this!